# python3 how to get the parent of a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

From my current script, I want to go to the sibling of parent. For example, 
my scriptA.py file is inside directory

```
-DirA
| |-ScriptA
|
-DirB
  |-FileB
  |-FileC
```

In this example, I have tried to represent the folder structure. I want to access the FileB/ FileC from ScriptA. So basically, I will first go to the DirB and then access them as these directories are also created dynamically hence hard-coding these will not work.

Comment: What happens when there's more directories that may have the same filenames? (And how do you think sibling order would work exactly in regards to a filesystem?)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @EricDuminil, I tried the regular os methods like chdir

Comment: Please show what you tried then, it makes it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent directory using `os.path`

```
import os.path
dir_of_this_file = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, os.pardir))
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir_of_this_file, os.pardir))
dir_b = parent_dir + "/DirB"
```

Comment: It's not clear if `DirB` is known.

Comment: oh, it looked that way to me, `glob` would work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write any code so I won't give a complete solution.

[`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob) could help you:

```
from glob import glob

print(glob('../*/*.py'))
# ['../DirA/scriptA.py', '../DirB/scriptB.py', '../DirB/scriptC.py']
```

You then need a way to filter those scripts and pick the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at os: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Functions you may find handy:
`os.getcwd()` get current working directory
`os.chdir(path)` Change your working directory to path given
`os.listdir(path=None)` get list of contents in current dir, or path given.

Good luck.